# In Experimental Design, Why is Graeco Latin Square cannot be Computed for specific length of Treatments?

Tags: r, experimental-design

In Experimental Design, I tried to design a `Graeco Latin-Square`, which I believe an extended version of `Latin Square` Design with more factors.. however, I found it behave strangely, here is some snippets by Using Treatment 1, and 2 Simulation with length of 1-26

```
graeco_design_possibility <- function(test_until=20){
  library(agricolae)
  k_graeco <- seq(2,test_until,1)
  bool_possibility <- c()
  for(n in 2:test_until){
    b <- design.graeco(LETTERS[1:n], 1:n)
    if(is.null(b)){
      bool_possibility <- c(bool_possibility, FALSE)
    }else{
      bool_possibility <- c(bool_possibility, TRUE)
    }
  }
  simulation_graeco <- data.frame(number_k = k_graeco, success_run=bool_possibility)
  return(simulation_graeco)
}
```

And When I test this, the simulation, resulted like below: (Note: More weird bugs happen after k=26)

```
g <- graeco_design_possibility(26)
g
   number_k success_run
1         2        TRUE
2         3        TRUE
3         4        TRUE
4         5        TRUE
5         6       FALSE
6         7        TRUE
7         8        TRUE
8         9        TRUE
9        10        TRUE
10       11        TRUE
11       12        TRUE
12       13        TRUE
13       14       FALSE
14       15        TRUE
15       16       FALSE
16       17        TRUE
17       18       FALSE
18       19        TRUE
19       20       FALSE
20       21        TRUE
21       22       FALSE
22       23        TRUE
23       24       FALSE
24       25        TRUE
25       26       FALSE
```

And thats how it is, I looked at the documentation, and it says that **The function is only for squares of the odd numbers and even numbers (4, 8, 10 and 12)** I didnt understand the explanation much, since the result of simulation kinda contradict with the explanation: 6,14,16 is even number right? so why the problem persist in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed limitations the developer supposed to limit in `design.graeco()` function, I honestly didnt know why there should be limitation on specific lengths on treatment, here is the final result of no limitation with Graeco Latin Square designs

```
design_graeco_custom <- function(trt1, trt2, serie = 2, seed = 0, kinds = "Super-Duper", randomization = TRUE){
  number <- 10
  if (serie > 0) 
    number <- 10^serie
  r <- length(trt1)
  if (seed == 0) {
    genera <- runif(1)
    seed <- .Random.seed[3]
  }
  set.seed(seed, kinds)
  parameters <- list(design = "graeco", trt1 = trt1, 
                     trt2 = trt2, r = r, serie = serie, seed = seed, kinds = kinds, 
                     randomization)
  col <- rep(gl(r, 1), r)
  fila <- gl(r, r)
  fila <- as.character(fila)
  fila <- as.numeric(fila)
  plots <- fila * number + (1:r)
  C1 <- data.frame(plots, row = factor(fila), col)
  
  C2 <- C1
  a <- 1:(r * r)
  dim(a) <- c(r, r)
  for (i in 1:r) {
    for (j in 1:r) {
      k <- i + j - 1
      if (k > r) 
        k <- i + j - r - 1
      a[i, j] <- k
    }
  }
  m <- trt1
  if (randomization) 
    m <- sample(trt1, r)
  C1 <- data.frame(C1, m[a])
  m <- trt2
  if (randomization) 
    m <- sample(trt2, r)
  C2 <- data.frame(C2, m[a])
  ntr <- length(trt1)
  C1 <- data.frame(C1, B = 0)
  for (k in 1:r) {
    x <- C1[k, 4]
    i <- 1
    for (j in 1:(r^2)) {
      y <- C2[(k - 1) * r + i, 4]
      if (C1[j, 4] == x) {
        C1[j, 5] <- y
        i <- i + 1
      }
    }
  }
  
  C1[, 4] <- as.factor(C1[, 4])
  C1[, 5] <- as.factor(C1[, 5])
  names(C1)[4] <- c(paste(deparse(substitute(trt1))))
  names(C1)[5] <- c(paste(deparse(substitute(trt2))))
  outdesign <- list(parameters = parameters, 
                    sketch = matrix(paste(C1[,4], C1[,5]), 
                                    byrow = TRUE, ncol = r), book = C1)
  return(outdesign)
}
```

And also I found out that with treatment over 26, I decided to use extra helper function to spawn possible letters:

```
letters_construction <- function(n=27, format_letter="upper"){
  if(n > 26 && n <= 702){
    letter_result <- NULL
    letter_comb <- NULL
    if(format_letter=="upper"){
      letter_result <- LETTERS[1:26]
      letter_comb <- expand.grid(LETTERS[1:26], LETTERS[1:26])
    }else if(format_letter=="lower"){
      letter_result <- letters[1:26]
      letter_comb <- expand.grid(letters[1:26], letters[1:26])
    }
    letter_comb$comb <- paste0(letter_comb$Var2, letter_comb$Var1)
    letter_finalcomb <- as.character(letter_comb$comb)
    n_remainder <- n-26
    letter_result <- c(letter_result, letter_finalcomb[1:n_remainder])
    return(letter_result)
  }
}
```

So I can make an implementation of Big Graeco Latin Square design like this:

```
b <- letters_construction(30)
design_graeco_custom(b, 1:30)
```